# How do I change the deployment credentials in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I want to deploy a report to a report server (SSRS) from Visual Studio. The (domain) account that's saved in Visual Studio does not have permissions on the report server. How do I change the user credentials to a different user that does have permissions, preferably a SQL Server account? Visual Studio simply fails out without giving me the option to try a different account.

```
Error rsAccessDenied : The permissions granted to user 'domain\user' are insufficient for performing this operation.
```

Comment: You need permission to deploy to be able to deploy. If you don't have the permissions to do so ask your DBA to grant you the correct permissions. If they won't give it to you, then they aren't doing so for a reason (and you shouldn't be deploying reports to a server you're not allowed). Also, there is no SQL Server authentication on SSRS.

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck with the same error message because I entered the wrong credentials on the first attempted deployment, and Visual Studio saved those for the next attempts. After restarting Visual Studio, I was allowed to enter different credentials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the report connection; provide the connection string in the General tab and select to use the Windows Authentication (Integrated Security) in the Credentials tab.
2. In SSRS server, create a data source. In the Connect Using section, select 'Credentials stored securely in the report server' and enter in the login info for the service account. Make sure you click the check box for 'Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source'.
3. Deploy the report to SSRS and assign the report to use the new data source.
4. Make sure the service account has permissions to execute any queries in SQL server